# update ngModel from directive

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 project I have a custom directive.Inside this directive I have to update some model value when user press `tab` so I ned to update some ngModel field:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appEnforcedInputs]'
})

export class EnforcedInputsDirective {

    @Input() enforce: NgModel;


    @HostListener('keydown.tab', ['$event']) onClick($event) {
        this.setValue()
    }

    setValue() {

        this.enforce.viewToModelUpdate(value);

        this.enforce.valueAccessor.writeValue(value)
        }
}
```

But if I try with: `viewToModelUpdate` and `writeValue` I see the correct value in the field but it seems like the validity is not updated (I see the validation error messages under the fields)